# How to change css of an element in shadow Dom when the main dom contains a class

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

This is the code:

```
<html>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div id="shadow_host">
      #shadow-root(open)          
    <div class="child-div">some random things</div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</html>
```

I have append a shadow dom to an element. I want to change the css of the element with the class child-div when ever the main dom has a parent element with class parent-div. Is it possible to do from css like

```
.parent-div .child-div{
   display:none
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:host-context()` CSS fonction in the Shadow DOM style.

```
:host-context(.parent-div) .child-div{
   display:none
}
```

```js
document.querySelector( '#shadow_host' )
    .attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
    .innerHTML = `
        <style>
            :host-context(.parent-div) .child-div {
                display:none
            }
        </style>
        <div class="child-div">some random things</div>
    `
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div id="shadow_host">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Heads up, it looks as though `:host-context()` is likely to be dropped from spec:
https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1914

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `::shadow` selector to style elements in the Shadow DOM.

You can also add a `<style>` tag to the shadow DOM using javascript's `.innerHTML` function and style it that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
#shadow_host::part(native) {
  color: black;
  border: dashed 2px black;
  background-color: #fec0ff;
}

#shadow_host::part(button):hover {
  background-color: #fd8fff;
}
```

Comment: #shadow_host is the ID of Parent Element that have Shadow Elements.